# GGanimate (R) : creating an animation vs a series of images

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am following this tutorial over here on using the R library 'gganimate' to create an animation of some times series data I simulated:

https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/gganimate-how-to-create-plots-with-beautiful-animation-in-r/

(scroll to the middle)

First, I created some data

```
#create data
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

car_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,105,8)

other_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,104,9)

final_dataset <- cbind(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars, car_damages_in_dollars, other_damages_in_dollars)

final_dataset <- as.data.frame(final_dataset)
```

Then, I converted the data into long format and changed the date types:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dd = melt(final_dataset, id=c("date_decision_made"))
dd$date_decision_made <- as.Date(as.character(dd$date_decision_made),'%Y/%m/%d')
```

Then, I tried to create the animations

```
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(
    dd,
    aes(date_decision_made, value, group = variable, color = factor(variable))
) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_color_viridis_d() +
    labs(x = "date", y = "dollars") +
    theme(legend.position = "top")

p + 
  geom_point() +
  transition_reveal(date_decision_made)
```

However, this produced 100 distinct images instead of an animation. Is it possible to fix this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate your problem. Your code worked fine for me to create the animation itself. But your data creation part is problematic: not sure where you learned to create a data frame by `cbind`, but please don't do it. Just use `data.frame` directly. And don't the date variable to character & bac to date again.

Comment: @Z.Lin: thank you for your reply, I made the change to 'data.frame'. I also had to install the 'magick' library in R for the animation to run. Here is a screenshot of the animation: https://imgur.com/a/4O8cq9s ... as you can see, the y-axis on this graph looks very cluttered. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Your y variable `value` is character, not numeric. That's why I don't recommend `cbind`; it converts all the variables to the same type (character in this case). Convert it to numeric & try again.

Comment: @Z.Lin: thank you! Now i am trying to recreate this entire code using the 'tweenr' library instead of 'gganimate' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599316/r-translating-code-from-gganimate-to-tweenr-time-series  thank you for all your help!